# Is this dimmer compatible a DC 12v power supply?

Tags: power-supply, led-strip, dimmer, electrical

This power supply is used for LED strip lights I recently purchased. I want to know if the dimmer below can be used with the power supply. The PS is AC 100-240v (IN) to DC 12v (OUT), while the dimmer is DC 12-24v (IN/OUT), based on my intuition, this should work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: looks ok........

Comment: THe Dimmer that is.... but are you sure LEDs take 50W?

Comment: The power supply is included with the LED lights kit, so I'm not concerned about it not working, my concern was the dimmer because it's generic and made by a different manufacturer.

Comment: OK then its less than 24W which sounds right for a 5m reel.  no problem on dimmer.

Comment: Tony, does it matter how the wires from the power supply connect to the dimmer IN input?

Comment: Polarity matters and is well marked.  Other than than cut the wire, and split into dimmer where convenient.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have looked at the power (in W) and made sure the dimmer can handle it, it should be fine.

If there is a 12V supply and the dimmer states 12-24V, then you should have no issues. Just double check wiring!

Comment: Thanks, just a quick follow up, the dimmer above is PWM, but they also offer a non-PWM version, what's the difference?

Comment: You would have to look at the datasheets to find that out and compare them!